# Let three signed measures such that $\lambda_{1}\bot\mu$ and $\lambda_{2}\bot\mu$, then $\left(\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}\right)\bot\mu$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The next question I found in my teacher's notes that are in preparation, so that is not trusted:

> Let $\lambda_{1}$, $\lambda_{1}$ and $\mu$  signed measures such that
>   $\lambda_{1}\bot\mu$ y $\lambda_{2}\bot\mu$, then
>   $\left(\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}\right)\bot\mu$.

Where, considering $\left(X,\mathcal{M}\right)$  be a measurable space,   $\lambda:\mathcal{M}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is called ***signed measure*** ( or ***charge***) if:

1. $\lambda\left(\phi\right)=0,$
2. If $\left\{ E_{i}\right\} _{i=1}^{\infty}$ is  a disjoint family of elements in $\mathcal{M}$, then $$\lambda\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_{i}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda\left(E_{i}\right),$$ where the serie on the right-hand side must be unconditionally convergent.

Moreover, we say that two  measures $\lambda$ and $\mu$  are ***mutually singular*** if there are disjoint sets $A$, $B$ in $\mathcal{M}$ such that $X=A\cup B$ and $\lambda\left(A\right)=\mu\left(B\right)=0$. In this case we write $\lambda\bot\mu$.

If $\lambda$ is signed measure and $\mu$ is measure, we e say that $\lambda$ and $\mu$  are ***mutually singular*** if $\left|\lambda\right|\perp\mu$, where $\left|\lambda\right|$ is the ***total variation*** of $\lambda$, i,e, $\left|\lambda\right|=\lambda^{+}+\lambda^{-}$.

**Question:** Notice that the definition of ***mutually singular*** for $\lambda$ and $\mu$  involves the need always $\mu$ is a measure, this is one of the reasons I think the problem is ill-posed, however, I need an example of three charges to show that the problem statement It's not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a signed measure, we can always write it as a difference of two positive measure by Hahn decomposition theorem so I think the problem is not ill-posed because you can $\lambda$ can be written as $\lambda_1-\lambda_2$ and $\mu=\mu_1-\mu_2$ where $\lambda_i,\mu_j$ are positive measure. Then $\lambda\perp \mu$ just means $\lambda_i\perp \mu_j$ for all $i,j$.